# In TestCafe Studio, how can I import/reference selectors/functions/custom scripts defined in one fixture into another?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

If I define a selector or function in one test, can I access it in another test or a test in another file/fixture? Similarly, is there a way to implement page models and for tests to use selectors defined within page?

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe Studio does not allow sharing selectors and functions defined via the "Define Element Selector" and "Define Function" actions in codeless testing. However, you can import selectors using the [Run TestCafe Script](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts#run-testcafe-script) action.

For example:

[image]